# Expansion in precompiled l3keys

Tags: expl3, expansion, l3keys

I'm having some issues with expansion in precompiled l3keys. I'd like to define a command `\NewThm{<name>}[<options>]` that sets the displayed theorem name to be a titlecased version of the given `<name>` if no option `name` is given, and the value of `name` otherwise. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { thmkeys/thm }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl,
  }

\tl_new:N \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl
\keys_precompile:nnN { thmkeys/thm }
  {
    name = \text_titlecase:n { \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl },
  }
  \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl

\NewDocumentCommand { \NewThm } { m O{} }
  { 
  % Store envname
    \tl_set:Nn \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl { #1 }
  % Set default keys
    \tl_use:N \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl
  % Set env-specific keys
    \keys_set:nn { thmkeys/thm } { #2 }
  % Call \newtheorem
    \thmkeys_thm_new:nV { #1 } \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \thmkeys_thm_new:nn \newtheorem
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thmkeys_thm_new:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewThm{theorem}
\NewThm{prop}[name=\textit{Proposition}]
\NewThm{lemma}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
text
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
text
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
text
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image: thms]

I understand why it fails as is: `\l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl` is not expanded during the call of `\NewThm`, so every theorem without a given `name` key will have the same displayed name.

Some thing's I've tried to fix it:

1. Tell `\newtheorem` to use `e`-type expansion, as in `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thmkeys_thm_new:nn { ne }`. This fixes the shown issue but fails if the `name` key contains things other than pure text, like the example `name=\textit{proposition}`.
2. Manually expand the argument of `\text_titlecase:nn`. Adding `\exp_args:Ne` (or `V` or `f`) before `\text_titlecase:n { \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl }` has no effect.

How else can I expand `\l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl` during the definition of `\NewThm` so that it doesn't break when it contains commands?

Comment: Why are you setting your `envname` variable instead of directly setting your `name` variable? This seems like an unnecessary indirection.

Comment: In the less minimal code there are other keys and my goal was to keep them all in `\keys_precompile` where I can't say `name = \text_titlecase:n { #1 }`. There are supposedly speed benefits to precompiling but perhaps that's negated by the misdirection...

Comment: @Skillmon Ah I misunderstood. You meant I should do `\tl_set:Nn \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl { \text_titlecase:n { #1 } }`. That is clearly better. Please feel free to post as an answer

Comment: yes originally I meant to simply do a `\tl_set:Nn` (well, actually a `\tl_set:Ne`/`\tl_set:Nx` -- better to pay the `\text_titlecase:n` overhead once even if unnecessary than on each usage later out in the document), but I think I added a slightly different answer, that might be more interesting, as it shows different ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\text_expand:n` to have a sort of expansion that should work for commands (there might be edge cases which aren't handled correctly though, `\text_expand:n` isn't the most simple macro).

But honestly, I think it's easier to set the name macro in an different way than via a variable in a frozen/precompiled kv-list.

Anyways, first the code that shows your current way, but with `\text_expand:n`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { thmkeys/thm }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl,
  }

\tl_new:N \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl
\keys_precompile:nnN { thmkeys/thm }
  {
    name = \text_titlecase:n { \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl },
  }
  \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl

\NewDocumentCommand { \NewThm } { m O{} }
  { 
  % Store envname
    \tl_set:Nn \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl { #1 }
  % Set default keys
    \tl_use:N \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl
  % Set env-specific keys
    \keys_set:nn { thmkeys/thm } { #2 }
  % Call \newtheorem
    \thmkeys_thm_new:ne { #1 } { \text_expand:n { \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl } }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \thmkeys_thm_new:nn \newtheorem
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thmkeys_thm_new:nn { ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewThm{theorem}
\NewThm{prop}[name=\textit{Proposition}]
\NewThm{lemma}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
text
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
text
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
text
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

---

A variant that doesn't use a precompiled kv-list but instead sets the default (at least for `name`) inside of `\keys_set:nn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { thmkeys/thm }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl,
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \NewThm } { m O{} }
  { 
  % Store envname
    \tl_set:Nn \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl { #1 }
  % Set env-specific keys
    \exp_args:Nne \keys_set:nn { thmkeys/thm }
      { name = { \text_titlecase:n {#1} }, \exp_not:n {#2} }
  % Call \newtheorem
    \thmkeys_thm_new:nV { #1 } { \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \thmkeys_thm_new:nn \newtheorem
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thmkeys_thm_new:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewThm{theorem}
\NewThm{prop}[name=\textit{Proposition}]
\NewThm{lemma}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
text
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
text
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
text
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

---

Another version using `expkv`<sup>1</sup> instead of `l3keys`. `expkv` also features precompiling key lists, but inside of `expkv` the precompilation works slightly different. Here the key list isn't fixed (well, the key list is, but not the values), but instead `\ekvcompile` works like `\cs_set:Npn` with key-value processing intervined. This way, you can precompile your keys, but still give different values to the individual keys via macro arguments.

In `expkv-def` (a kv-list based frontend to define keys in `expkv`) the equivalent of `.tl_set:N` is named `store`. Note that `expkv` uses space-delimited prefixes instead of `.`-separated postfixes to denote the key types.

The drawback is that you mix in non-L3-syntax into your code, as `exkpv` isn't programmed in L3, and has no frontend for it.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of `expkv`</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{expkv-def}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ekvdefinekeys { thmkeys/thm }
  {
    store~ name = \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl
  }
\ekvcompile \__thmkeys_defaults:n #1 { thmkeys/thm } { name = {#1} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__thmkeys_defaults:n { e }

\NewDocumentCommand { \NewThm } { m O{} }
  { 
  % Store envname
    \tl_set:Nn \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl { #1 }
  % Set defaults
    \__thmkeys_defaults:e { \text_titlecase:n { \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl } }
  % Set env-specific keys
    \ekvset { thmkeys/thm } { #2 }
  % Call \newtheorem
    \thmkeys_thm_new:nV { #1 } { \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \thmkeys_thm_new:nn \newtheorem
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thmkeys_thm_new:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewThm{theorem}
\NewThm{prop}[name=\textit{Proposition}]
\NewThm{lemma}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
text
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
text
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
text
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

---

Yet another pure L3 answer could be to, instead of setting your `name` key directly to your `envname`, set it to `\q_no_value`, and later check whether it's `\q_no_value`, and if so, use your `envname`.

This variant has the additional advantage that `\text_titlecase:n` is only used if really necessary (and `\text_titlecase:n` is comparatively slow).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { thmkeys/thm }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl,
  }

\tl_new:N \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl
\keys_precompile:nnN { thmkeys/thm }
  {
    name = \q_no_value,
  }
  \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl

\NewDocumentCommand { \NewThm } { m O{} }
  { 
  % Store envname
    \tl_set:Nn \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl { #1 }
  % Set default keys
    \tl_use:N \l_thmkeys_thm_defaultkeys_tl
  % Set env-specific keys
    \keys_set:nn { thmkeys/thm } { #2 }
  % Call \newtheorem
    \quark_if_no_value:NTF \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl
      {
        \thmkeys_thm_new:ne {#1}
          { \text_titlecase:n { \l_thmkeys_thm_envname_tl } }
      }
      { \thmkeys_thm_new:nV {#1} \l_thmkeys_thm_name_tl }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \thmkeys_thm_new:nn \newtheorem
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thmkeys_thm_new:nn { nV, ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewThm{theorem}
\NewThm{prop}[name=\textit{Proposition}]
\NewThm{lemma}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
text
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
text
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
text
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. General question: is this method of setting a key to `\q_no_value` and branching with `\quark_if_no_value:NTF` faster than setting the key to be empty and branching with `\tl_if_empty:NTF`?

Comment: @mbert they are equally fast (or at least immeasurably different). Both are equal to a simple `\ifx` comparison, the difference is to what this is compared. But the `\q_no_value` is the better flag for no name given, as `\q_no_value` is really unlikely to be user input.